# Typescript sort objects array with null parameter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

we have an objects array (Angular CLI: 7.2.3,Angular: 7.2.2) that we sort by object parameter:

```
    users.users.sort((a, b) => 
a.first_name.localeCompare(b.first_name, 'en', {'sensitivity': 'base'}))
```

some of a.first_name are Null and we got *"Cannot read properties of null (reading 'localeCompare')".*
I want to validate data during sort and let this value "" when it is null.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour to get a better understanding about https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Another good read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions?. Afterwards, please edit your question to add all the relevant code

Comment: please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: you could fallback to "" using `users.users.sort((a, b) => (a.first_name || "").localeCompare(b.first_name, 'en', {'sensitivity': 'base'}))`

Comment: @dm you can also use `Nullish coalescing operator (??)` for topic read this
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Comment: as Nsevens mentionned you could use the default `""` value with `(a.first_name ?? "")` the `??` operator only goes on its right side when the left side is `null` or `undefined`

Comment: @nsevens thanks - those are good solutions.